# Games where a parent or entangled and caring care person must make choices

Tags: game

I am looking for a game, where there player has to achieve the maximum smoothening and heartening emotions.

In the game, there are various characters, including people of all ages and teenagers and children.

The character, has to choose:

- where to stand
- what body language to use
- where to go
- what to say
- what to do
- when to be present, and when to let the various characters take charge and do the things unfold
- what to think (somehow, this configures the other player's actions, and, what happens).

...

In the game, icons are placed by the player's heart, and special effects are used to portray the overall mood.

The user, during the game, can control, speech, motion, what is said, etc.

As the user plays, the user gets to get to grips with what to choose to obtain optimal effects.

I wonder if a game for Android smartphones like that has been developed?

It could allow children and parents to reason about courses of action, and, make (in, an empowered, manner), the best choices for everyone, (and, people would be satisfied with it).

Has anything like that been developed?

Would anyone be willing to develop such software?

Where can I find, such games?

Thanks.